Multiclass matrix loss function in scikit-learn / xgboost / lightgbm
I have data with 4 classes: $c_1, c_2, c_3, c_4$.
I'd like to create a classifier which has different scaling for the loss function per class combination:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} 0 & l \left( \hat{c}_{1}, {c}_{2} \right) & l \left( \hat{c}_{1}, {c}_{3} \right) & l \left( \hat{c}_{1}, {c}_{4} \right) \\ l \left( \hat{c}_{2}, {c}_{1} \right) & 0 & l \left( \hat{c}_{2}, {c}_{3} \right) & l \left( \hat{c}_{2}, {c}_{4} \right) \\ l \left( \hat{c}_{3}, {c}_{1} \right) & l \left( \hat{c}_{3}, {c}_{2} \right) & 0 & l \left( \hat{c}_{3}, {c}_{4} \right) \\ l \left( \hat{c}_{3}, {c}_{1} \right) & l \left( \hat{c}_{3}, {c}_{2} \right) & l \left( \hat{c}_{3}, {c}_{3} \right) & 0 \end{bmatrix} $$
Where $l \left( \hat{c}_{i}, {c}_{j} \right)$ is the loss factor for estimating the $i$ th class where the sample has the $j$ th class.
The motivation is to have a larger loss for some mistakes.
Some of scikit-learn models (RandomForestClassifier, HistGradientBoostingClassifier) allows setting a value per row by class_weight.
It is also supported by lightgbm's LGBMClassifier.
Is there way to achieve something arbitrary as the matrix above for xgboost / scikit-learn or lightgbm?
Is there any other classifier in the Python eco system to support such a generic matrix?
It seems to be supported to some degree in the deep learning case: Loss for ordered multi class data in classification.
Is seems to be very useful for many cases in classification.
